# Self-walking robot with Raspberry Pi Cam object detection

Tags: raspbian-stretch

I am now trying to make a self-walking robot with Raspberry Pi and Raspberry Pi camera. But i am now facing several difficulties and wish to gain insight from here,

My final goal: An robot able to walk itself, avoiding the obstacles detected by the camera.

> Q1: Should i do it offline or online? I can set up a server on AWS and get the video / images from the Raspberry Pi and do the object detection

My plan:

1) Able to do **real-time** object detection

2) Detect the distance from the robot itself and the detected object

I have tried `uv4l` and `RPi-Cam-Web-Interface` to get the video / image from the Raspberry Pi camera.

uv4l has a few seconds delay and for better real-time video i go for `RPi-Cam-Web-Interface`. But i can only find web-interface for the `RPi-Cam-Web-Interface`

But

> How to get video stream from `RPi-Cam-Web-Interface`?
>
> For uv4l, how to connect uv4l with tensorflow and get the result?

I saw examples running on web, but for the robot to walk, i need to get the results and then tell the robot to walk into which direction.

If i go for `RPi-Cam-Web-Interface`, and could not get the video stream, i can do something like refreshing the image i can get from the web, but it cost a lot of http traffic and will induce delay.

> Any ideas on what i should do here?
>
> Q2: How to better detect distance with the Raspberry pi Camera?
>   I have got the ultrasonic sensor but it is kind of unable to relate the distance get from the sensor and the object detected

Sorry i am very new to it and have lost direction when encountering the real-time object detection. Please forgive me if i have asked something which looks easy to you.

Comment: This appears to be far too broad a question for this site.  It looks like you need to do more research into each of the areas you mention.

Comment: Agree with Joan. Also tensorflow object detection on the rpi is really slow. It's also probably uneccessary. If all you want to do it avoid objects, you can do that with ultrasound, laser, or similar that don't need object detection.

Comment: As others have told you, this question is too broad. In it, you have already laid out some of the system components that you need to build/program. My suggestion is that you first try to achieve image recognition on a Raspberry Pi. Then try to build simple robots that follow a predefined path or do simple object avoidance. If you have specific, technical questions along the way, post them here.